# More efficient way to check DataTable values?

Tags: c#, datatable

I want to iterate through my table, check to see if the Quantity received is higher than the quantity expected for each row, and if so execute some code.

The way I've done it below feels amateurish.

```
bool allRecieved = true;
foreach (DataRow row in SubVwr.Tables[0].Tbl.Rows)
{
    if(row["QtyRcvd"] < row["QtyPer"]) allRecieved = false;
}
if(allRecieved) // execute code
```

Comment: Break from the loop as soon as you find a fault; no need to iterate over the entire table.

Comment: First thing to challenge: why do you need to use `DataTable`? in virtually all cases when I see `DataTable`, it is being used inappropriately, and a non-`DataTable` approach would work *much more efficiently and more conveniently*. There *are* legitimate good use-cases for `DataTable`, but they shouldn't be a default, and if you know the members that it has (`QtyRcvd` / `QtyPer`) then it *almost certainly* isn't one of those cases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use LINQ, for better readability (presuming those are `int`-columns):

```
bool allRecieved = SubVwr.Tables[0].Tbl.AsEnumerable()
    .All(row => row.Field<int>("QtyRcvd") >= row.Field<int>("QtyPer"));
```

An advantage over your current loop is that this will stop as soon as one record doesn't match this condition. Your loop will continue until end without `break`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit radical, but I'd start by ***not using `DataTable`***, and instead use a simple model:

```
public class SomeType {
    // I'd probably name these QuantityReceived etc, but... meh
    public int QtyRcvd {get;set;}
    public int QtyPer {get;set;}
    // ... etc
}
```

Then I can very conveniently check properties etc. For example, to mirror [Tim Schmelter's LINQ answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49280194/23354):

```
List<SomeType> someData = ...
var allReceived = someData.All(x => x.QtyRcvd >= x.QtyPer);
```

so now all we need is to load `SomeType` from the DB, which is where ORMs and micro-ORMs excel. For example, with "Dapper", this would be:

```
string region = "North"; // just to show parameter usage
var someData = connection.Query<SomeType>(
    @"select * from SomeTable where Region=@region", new { region }).AsList();
```